# How to diagnose in Qt why "unable to open file"

Tags: opengl, cmake, qt5

I am trying to run the 
https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/examples/opengl/cube?h=5.13
example. It builds fine, starts up, then gives the message

```
QOpenGLShader: Unable to open file ":/vshader.glsl"
QOpenGLShader: Unable to open file ":/fshader.glsl"
QOpenGLTexture::setData() tried to set a null image
```

The files are there, the .qrc file found (I think from the message),
What can be the problem? (the error message is not helpful in locating he reason) The files are there, readable (by the other applications), 
already moved all files in the same subdirectory.

Comment: `:/` looks suspiciously like not the correct path

Comment: You are right, but I just downloaded the sample.

Comment: My guess would be that the resources `:/vshader.glsl` and `:/fshader.glsl` are not being bound as part of the build process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried to run the example on Qt5.13 windows 10 MSVC2017 64 bit without a problem so there must be something else going on here.

the same example is already installed in Your Qt installation directory. Can you try it from there? Should work.

Do you have Read write rights? Are all files in the same folder as the pro file?

Can you open the qrc file in Qt Creator and see if you have missing links?

Comment: Actually, I am using CMake, and probably handling of the qrc files is the reason.